# OneToOne Cannot delete even on Cascade All

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem when try to delete a onetoone. 
So I want to delete the "Page" object which has a one to one relation with PageImage, but if fails, and telling that this is not possible due to "PAGE_IMAGES__PAGES_FK" .

Now, I really don't understand what is the issue here, I am using cascade all.

Hibernate 4.1 + Spring 3.1 + Mysql

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGES")
public class Page
....
@NotNull
@BatchSize(size = 200)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "page", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
public PageImage getImage() {
    return image;
}
....


@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE_IMAGES"

@NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAGE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "PAGE_IMAGES__PAGES_FK")
    public Page getPage() {
        return page;
    }
```

`entityManager.remove(myPage);` fails with exception "constraint fails"

Comment: Remove unnecessary associations,  use on delete - cascade.

Comment: What do you mean by unnecessary associations? Shouldn't Cascade = All  do all the job (removing the pageImage also)? Thank you

Comment: Ensure you have given cascade for ON DELETE at your DB table.

Answer (score 2):

in your mapping PageImage is the owner of relationship since mappedBy = "page"

therefore, you have: 
page has a reference to pageImage
pageImage has a reference to page

you try to delete the children thus the exception. Is very likely that if you try to delete pageImage it will just work.